# Perl::Critic in Brutal Mode

Tags: perl, perl-critic

So I've recently started using `Perl::Critic` to check the quality of the code I've written. I'm running it in brutal mode and have one suggestion it is making which I don't understand as being an issue. The output is:

`Return value of flagged function ignored - print at line 197, column 13.  See pages 208,278 of PBP.  (Severity: 1)`

This is basically a call to the print function with a short message which outputs to the console. Why then should I capture the return value which will almost certainly always be 1 as I can't think of any use case where this wouldn't be a 1.

Is brutal mode being 'too brutal'? Or am I missing something? I should add that I did read pages 208 and 278 of the PBP and the answer is not clear to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree that most of the time `print` will not fail.  But, you can disable this function by creating a `.perlcriticrc` file and adding these lines to it (like I do):

```
# Check all builtins except "print"
[InputOutput::RequireCheckedSyscalls]
functions = :builtins
exclude_functions = print
```

This is described in [Perl::Critic::Policy::InputOutput::RequireCheckedSyscalls](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::InputOutput::RequireCheckedSyscalls)

Also, if you disagree with all the policies of the Brutal setting, you can just use one of the other 4 less brutal settings.  The tool is highly configurable.

Here is a trivial case where `print` can fail (printing to a closed filehandle):

```
open my $fh, '>', 'out';
print $fh "555\n";
close $fh;
print $fh "888\n" or die "print failed: $!";

# we shouldn't get here
print "777\n";
```

In such short code, it is obvious that you just closed the filehandle, and you would never then try to print to it.  But, if you had a lot of (poorly designed) code, maybe it would occur.

There are other reasons `print` could fail, such as if another process came along and deleted a directory or disabled write permissions on your open file.

I created a script for myself to run `perlcritic` which makes it easy to access the POD for a given policy: [Sort and summarize perlcritic output](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1005951)

Answer (score 1):

One use case where `print "something";` fails is when STDOUT has been opened to a file and the file system is full. But in my projects I also do not check the return value of `print`.

Comment: Fun story: When we did disk writes on the nuclear power plant controlling computer, we didn't check for errors. That said, running out of disk space wasn't possible (since the disk didn't have a file system, and space was manually allocated during development), so the only possible errors were coding errors and disk failure. And if there was a disk failure, the whole computer would fail since programs had to be loaded from disk every 100 ms or so (to achieve multi-tasking on 32 KiW of RAM). There was simply no point to checking for errors.

Answer (score -1):

To implement the fix for

```perl
print "$updated_service_name\n";
```

Use

```perl
my $printed = (print "$updated_service_name\n");
if (!$printed) {
  die "Unable to write to stdout\n";
}
```